# How can I enable round backups?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

As far as I remember, there was a feature in CS:GO to backup rounds, however I can't find how to enable it. Also, when I checked my csgo folder, I saw some old round backups. Here is a picture of the last one (Notice the timestamp? It was my last day with my old pc. Also my last match was 10 mins ago):

[image: last backup]

Edit:
I also found the command `mp_backup_round_file`, but it is enabled.

More info:

```
"mp_backup_round_file" = "backup"  
"mp_backup_round_file_last" = ""  
"mp_backup_round_file_pattern" = "%prefix%_round%round%.txt"
```

Comment: Hi, Can you clarify what you mean by backing up rounds?

Comment: @DamonSmithies As you can see on pic, it shows everyones money, mvps who killed who, who won etc. Btw: it seems to be only working on friend-only servers.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the `mp_backup_restore_load_file` command, to which you provide a file containing a round's backup data. The filename is  on the convars `mp_backup_round_file` which provides a prefix and enables round backups as soon as it is set, and `mp_backup_round_file_pattern` which defines the full filename pattern for each round backup file as you have noted.

Simply use `mp_backup_restore_load_file`, which accepts a parameter which is the filename of the round you want to restore the game state to.

Note that as a simple way to restore the previous round, you can rely on `mp_backup_round_file_last` which contains the filename of the last backed up round. If you want to restore another round, you'll have to use the right backup file instead. These can be listed with `mp_backup_restore_list_files`.